# Column alias is not recognized in case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, calculated-columns

I have a case expression in a computed column in a query that will average values of `DATA_SCALE_1`, `DATA_SCALE_2`, `DATA_SCALE_3`, `DATA_SCALE_4` where all of which are of data type integer.

```
CASE  
    WHEN Form_Ref = 1091 
    THEN (DATA_SCALE_1 + DATA_SCALE_2 + DATA_SCALE_3 + DATA_SCALE_4)/4
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN DATA_SCALE_1 IS NOT NULL 
        THEN DATA_SCALE_1
        ELSE 
            OLD_FIELD_CUST_TBL.SELECT_TEXT
        END
END AS Satisfaction
```

`Form_Ref` is an alias of `dbo.SU_ENTITY_TYPE.Ref`. When I use `Form_Ref` in the condition, it always defaults to the ELSE clause. When I explicitly specify `dbo.SU_ENTITY_TYPE.Ref`, it performs the THEN clause but the computed average is rounded down to the nearest integer. I need it to be at most in two decimal places.

Any inputs on why the alias is not recognized? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

To limit average to two decimal places, I used 
`CAST(CaseExpression AS NUMERIC(x,2))` 
where `x` is the max count of digits including the 2 decimal numbers.

Comment: Divide by `4.0`. I assume that all `DATA_SCALE` fields are **integers**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need nested `case` statements.  This should produce the same logic:

```
(CASE WHEN Form_Ref = 1091 
      THEN (DATA_SCALE_1 + DATA_SCALE_2 + DATA_SCALE_3 + DATA_SCALE_4) / 4.0
      WHEN DATA_SCALE_1 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN DATA_SCALE_1
      ELSE OLD_FIELD_CUST_TBL.SELECT_TEXT
 END) AS Satisfaction
```

Second, column aliases cannot be used at the same level they are defined.  The behavior your are describing makes it sound like there is a column called `Form_Ref` in the tables (in the `from` clause) as well as `Form_Ref` being the target of an alias.